# Not able to copy and paste from my local machine to the Guacamole (vnc) session

Tags: reactjs, remote-server, remote-desktop, vnc, guacamole

I have a an application that is using the Apache Guacamole and Guacamole-Common-JS in the frontend. I am able to access the VNC session and copy and paste inside the same VNC session is working, however, I want to copy and paste from my local machine to the remote VNC session which I am not able to do. Is there any configuration which can enable the clipboard to be shared between the local and the remote machine?

I tried all the resources I could find but I couldn't find much help.

Comment: What does "all the resource" mean? Can you explain in your post what documentation you already consulted, and what you already searched for or even found that didn't apply? (Especially since clipboard use is _explicitly_ called out in https://guacamole.apache.org/faq/#clipboard)

Comment: I simply removed the guacamole-common-js library and now the copy and paste is working fine for telnet and SSH. Still need to figure out the issue with VNC though.

Comment: Great, but if you're posting to Stackoverflow, you do so not just "for you" but "for everyone", so your post needs to include [all the relevant details](/help/how-to-ask). Even if you're going to walk off and do more digging yourself, [edit] your post so that it's a complete question as per the posting guidelines.